# CMake does not properly include Boost with Linux

Tags: boost, cmake

I am using CMake to build a project on Windows and Linux.
My CMake script generates Visual Studio Solution correctly but on Linux I am getting error for boost include file during make.

---

## Error

hab@hab-VirtualBox:/media/sf_GitHub/corona/experimental/MakefileParser$ make install
[ 14%] Building CXX object MakefileParser/src/CMakeFiles/LibMakefileParser.dir/lex.yy.c.o
makefile.l:11:33: fatal error: boost\filesystem.hpp: No such file or directory
  #include **"boost\filesystem.hpp"**
                                 ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [MakefileParser/src/CMakeFiles/LibMakefileParser.dir/lex.yy.c.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [MakefileParser/src/CMakeFiles/LibMakefileParser.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

========================================================================

CMakeList.txt

```
SET (INCLUDES
    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/Config.h"
    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/defines.hpp"
    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/Expansion.h"
    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/MakefileParser.h"
    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/StringUtils.h"
)

SET (SOURCES
    "lex.yy.c"
    "makefile.tab.h"
    "Expansion.cpp"
    "MakefileParser.cpp"
    "StringUtils.cpp"
)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/ext/boost_1_60_0_Lite")
LINK_DIRECTORIES("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/ext/boost_1_60_0_Lite/stage/lib")

ADD_LIBRARY(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${SOURCES} ${INCLUDES})

SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES (${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)

SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES("lex.yy.c" PROPERTIES LANGUAGE CXX )

if(WIN32)
    INSTALL(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} 
    RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
else()
    INSTALL(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} 
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
    COMPONENT library)
endif()

SET(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} 

POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory "${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH}/$<CONFIGURATION>" ${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}/$<CONFIGURATION>

)
```

Has anybody encountered such problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `boost\filesystem.hpp` looks like windows file path, should be `boost/filesystem.hpp` in linux

Comment: You should use FindBoost, this makes it easier to get it working on several systems.

Comment: Yeah! It worked. Thank You.

Comment: Will try with FindBoost